# Split string by whitespaces, except for when whitespace is inside apostrophes

Tags: python, string, split

input: "A B C ' '"
desired output: ['A', 'B', 'C', " "]

I've tried a few solutions using the re package, but I m not very good with regex

Comment: then post what are those few solutions that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem based your example.
I have expanded the test string to show more than one whitespace inside of apostrophes.

```py
import re
test_string = "A B C ' ' D E F ' '"

pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z]\s)|('\s')")
matches = pattern.findall(test_string)

result = [m[0].strip() if m[0] else ' ' for m in matches]

print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', ' ', 'D', 'E', 'F', ' ']
```

Here is the explanation of the regex statement : `r"([A-Z]\s)|('\s')"`

- `([A-Z]\s)` : search for any CAPITAL letter `[A-Z]` followed by space `\s`. This is `group 1`
- `|` : OR statement
- `('\s')` : search for a space within apostrophes. This is `group 2`

I then use list comprehension to deal with the two groups retrieved using the `findall()` regex function.

Comment: Hello, i wasn't clear enough in the input output sample. I need something that also works for multiple characters like ' bsadbsa eps aaa c ' ' sd ' '". I apologize for that, i will figure it out from your solution.

Comment: Yes - communicating your requirements helps you to get the answer you need. But best to supply an input and output that best represents the activity you are trying to accomplish, and also the attempts that you have made in trying to get the final result. Between the two, you are more likely to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: `([A-Za-z]+\s)|('\s')`